# The conditions for planerity of comaximal ideal graph with 4 maximal ideals never hold

Tags: graph-theory, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, planar-graphs

There is proof for the claim that there is no comaximal ideal graph
Which contain 4 maximal ideals and also planer which is definitely true.
But some where else I saw an if and only if condition for a comaximal ideal graphs with 4 maximal ideals to be planer.
So now i'm try ing to show that conditions never hold.
But i got stuck...
First defined:
Mi=the set of all ideals including mi which are contained in The maximal ideal mi.
Vi=Mi - (union on Mj) where i is not the same as j.
Vij=(intersection of Mi and Mj)-Mk
Where k is not equal to i or j.
The conditions are: 
Vi=1 
Or
There exist only one Vi with cardinality 2 and Vjk and Vjkl are equal to null for distinct i, j,k